# Keep my thread running when starting new intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Here's the thing, I want to keep my thread running (it's downloading a file) when I start an intent (a media player to play what is downloading).

The problem is when I called my intent, the onPause method is automatically called.

So what should I do to avoid that ?

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity {

      MyThread my_thread;

      public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        //Starting My thread
        my_thread = new MyThread();
        my_thread.start();

        // Starting the intent 
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
        startActivity(intent);

      @Override
      protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Stop my thread
        my_thread.interrupt();

       } 
}
```

EDIT : I'm downloading a live stream so there is no end of it unless the user decide to close the activty.

Comment: Before starting the thread, check it with `isAlive()` and then use `.join()`, so that the download is finished when you start the new intent.

Comment: It's a live stream, so there is no end

Comment: What class name is `Activity` anyway? :P

Comment: Paste the code for the MediaPlayer, I must see how it interprets an unclosed (unfinished) file, if the Thread is not finishing it. I'll need the `MyThread` too.

Comment: The thread downloads the file and Vlc is good at playing continuous changing file's size but the problem is calling intent automatically will destroy my thread. Unless removing the interrupt() method and called it when the intent is closed maybe ...

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at AsyncTasks instead, they allow better multi threading on Android for these sort of things.

A quick example could look like this (from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Edit: didn't see it was a continuous stream, don't use the above code. Maybe you should put that in your original question?

Comment: If I set the code of (mythread.)start method in doInBackground and in my main activity I called a new intent will the AsyncTask be destroyed ?

Comment: No, just make sure it knows which activity to call if you're going to use a callback in onPostExecute

Comment: I was thinking doing something like. 1) DownloadFilesTask download = new DownloadFilesTask(); download.execute(); 2) Calling a media player through intent. Remember it's a continuous stream so I don't think onPostExecute will be called.

Comment: If it's a continuos stream don't use an AsyncTask, it will take too much system resources as it won't yeild to the other tasks. Use the DownloadManager instead.

Answer (score 0):

The OnPause event of a class extending Activity is always called when you start a new Activity, that is what you are doing with startActivity(intent).

If you want that your thread stop downloading data when you exit the application, that's what I think is the meaning of your myThread.interrupt()  into the OnPause callback, do not use "OnPause" but choose another event. You can find a nice description of what events are started when here: [Activity lifecycle](http://ogrelab.ikratko.com/activity-lifecycle-explained-in-details/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of:

1. (For api level 9 above): Use [`DownloadManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) to download the file and when you're done send a broadcast to notify that you've finished downloading and the Activity can use the file downloaded. These two articles ([this](http://sunil-android.blogspot.ro/2013/01/pass-data-from-service-to-activity.html) and [this](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/)) should help you out.
2. If you're developing for Froyo as well, a very similar approach: you can start an `IntentService` (that is doing its work on a serial background thread), download the file and when finished you'll send a broadcast intent containing the path where the file can be found. Here are two articles to help you with `IntentServices` ([this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/) and [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/))
3. Or you can use an `AsyncTask`.

For 1 and 2: In your activity you'll have to register a `BroadcastReceiver` that will handle above intents. Something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected BroadcastReceiver myDownloadCompleteReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if ("my_package.actions.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE".equals(intent.getAction())) {
                String filePath = intent.getStringExtra("DOWNLOAD_PATH");
                // use the filePath
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("my_package.actions.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(myDownloadCompleteReceiver, filter);
    }

}
```